# Insert 0's in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have list of lists as follows

```
list1=[['10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100'],['10','40'],['10','20','12'],...]
list2=[['2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010'],['2004','2005'],['2001','2002','2004'],...]
```

I want to add 0's to the list wherever an year doesn't exist in list2

```
list1_modified=[['10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100'],['0','0','0','10','40','0','0','0','0','0'],['10','20','0','12','0','0','0','0','0','0'],....]
```

How could I modify my first list in accordance with second list.

```
for val1,val2 in zip(list1,list2):
    if len(val1)!=len(val2):
       for sub1,sub2 in zip(val1,val2):
           sub1='0'
```

Comment: @venky__ most likely because OP did not demonstrate any effort to solve the issue, so this currently looks like a "I have A, I want B, please write the code for me" question, and SO is no code-writing service.

Comment: Also its not clear just where the `0`'s need to be added. They don't seem to be added just to the front or the back.

Comment: @MikeScotty updated the code too

Comment: So, you're saying that the first sub-list in `list2` is the master list which shows the correct translation from `list1`? Hmm, I suspect an X-Y problem here.

Comment: @quamrana I want the first list to be updated based on second list. If there is not value corresponding to second list in first list,it should be updated as '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
list1 = [['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'], ['10', '40'], ['10', '20', '12']]
list2 = [['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010'], ['2004', '2005'],
         ['2001', '2002', '2004']]

list1_modified = []
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    l1 = iter(l1)
    sub_list = [next(l1) if str(index+2001) in l2 else '0' for index in range(len(list1[0]))]
    list1_modified.append(sub_list)

print(list1_modified)
```

print:

```
[['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'], ['0', '0', '0', '10', '40', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['10', '20', '0', '12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

Comment: ``` [['15', '58', '30'], ['6'], ['113', '226', '180', '165', '236', '403', '822', '216', '208', '287'], ['46']]
[['2001', '2002', '2003'], ['2001'], ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010'], ['2008']]```.It doesn't work for these values @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: @Sam So what's the expected output for that?I am still not sure what you want.

Comment: worked after changing the len(list1[0])) to 10 @jizhihaoSAMA